# Tag suggestions

Tags: feature-request

Maybe I'm a little off, but I'd love to see a `Proliant` badge tag. There are quite a few HP ProLiant questions that surface on the site. At this point, I think I've had nearly as many ProLiant upvotes as I have had for Linux.

See:
https://serverfault.com/badges?tab=tags

Comment: [What are tag badges? How do they work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63835/what-are-tag-badges-how-do-they-work)

Comment: @jscott - you should post that as an answer

Comment: I'm referring to the Badges listed at: http://serverfault.com/badges?tab=tags

Answer (score 3):

The badge-list you see there is auto-generated. Any tag in which any user has earned enough rep to merit a badge will be in that list. Earn enough rep in the [proliant](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/proliant) tag, and you'll see the badge in there. From the looks of it, you're only [four upvotes short](https://serverfault.com/tags/proliant/topusers) of earning the Bronze tag-badge for that very tag. It'll be there soon!